# telnet localhost 25 vs telnet localhost 587

Tags: postfix, ssl, smtp

I install a postfix with the following `postconf -n`:(however I changed my domain to example.com)

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
enable_original_recipient = no
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
message_size_limit = 204800000
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, , localhost
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $smtpd_sender_login_maps $sender_bcc_maps $recipient_bcc_maps $smtp_generic_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_checks, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_limit = 25
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_invalid_hostname, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_checks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /srv/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000


# postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
inline
internal
memcache
mysql
nis
pipemap
proxy
randmap
regexp
socketmap
static
tcp
texthash
unionmap
unix
```

My `master.cf` is :

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n - - - - smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps inet n - - - - smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup fifo n - - 60 1 pickup
  -o content_filter=
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
smtp-amavis unix - - - - 2 smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o max_use=20
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n - - - - smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o local_recipient_maps=
  -o relay_recipient_maps=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
  -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
  -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters 
dovecot unix - n n - - pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $(recipient)
policy-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       -       spawn
     user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
     spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

When I use `telnet localhost 25` :

```
telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo example.com
250-mail.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 204800000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
auth login
503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled <== Error
```

Then When I telnet on 587 such as :

```
 $ telnet localhost 587
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo example.com
250-mail.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 204800000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
auth login
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first   <== error
```

I don't know to track and Tshoot which error. on port 587 or port 25 ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your question. You give some config and some output which shows some errors. But what exactly do you expect as output, i.e. what you are trying to achieve? What you showing is pretty standard behavior:  authentication is enabled on port 587 but only after upgrade to TLS so that passwords are not transmitted in clear. And authentication on the standard delivery port 25 is often disabled since this is for MTA to MTA delivery, not MUA to MTA.

Comment: I want to solve my problem and can login via smtp

Comment: Then you need to use port 587 with a client able to upgrade to TLS - telnet is not the right tool for this. Try `openssl s_client -connect localhost:587 -starttls smtp` instead.

Comment: Thank you man, You solved my problem.